# c# connection string (underlying provider error)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

This is my connection string, but i have problem when application is started after some time i get error: **The underlying provider failed!**
  I use entity framework, i think problem is connection string, please if have anyone who can check my connection string and view where is problem, thank you so much.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="rosewoodEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TITANIUM-PC;initial catalog=rosewood;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: are you using sql server?

Comment: yes yes, ms sql express